# Open the K Menu Editor from command line

Tags: command-line, kde, menu, plasma-5, kde5

I am using Excalibur as start menu. In contrast to other start menus, after right-clicking on Excalibur, there is no button "Edit Applications..." that would open the K Menu Editor. Switching to another start menu (and back) messes up my configuration of Excalibur. What alternative way exists to open the K Menu Editor - for example via the command line?

Comment: Not running KDE here, but isn't the command just `kmenuedit`?

Comment: @Terrance: *blush* it is... I could have tried this. To my defense: KDE sometimes has weird choices regarding their command line commands. If you just post it as a short answer, I will except it - then people are able to see that this was answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the command line just run `kmenuedit` to bring up the  K Menu Editor.

Hope this helps!